# Adding feature layer to ArcGIS Online from REST API?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online, arcgis-rest-api

I need to add a feature layer to ArcGIS Online account from code.

i have created a developer account where if i want to create a feature layer i  have to upload a CSV file and it makes the feature layer.

> Problem is: i need to create the sane feature layer using my code.
>   like is there any REST API or some API which ArcGIS provide this
>   option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've checked requests which were sent in ArcGIS Online to add Feature Service with Chrome dev tools and found that it uses 4 requests:

1. Create Service - create feature service with REST API without layers, see http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/#/Create_Service/02r30000027r000000/
2. update Service item - fix service name, see http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/#/Update_Item/02r30000009s000000/
3. addToDefinition request for admin part, see http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Add_To_Definition_Feature_Service/02r300000230000000/ - **this is the request to add layer definition into empty service**
4. Last request to updateDefinition of the service (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/#/Update_Definition_Feature_Service/02r30000021z000000/).

Answer (score 2):

There is definitely a REST API for working with ArcGIS Online and Portal.

This is the specific operation for publishing a hosted feature service from .csv

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Publish_Item/02r300000080000000/

Comment: Jhon thanks for reply.. but i'm looking for creating a feture layer from the code..